# How are different processes  scheduled to run on CPU,will a multi-threaded process hopefully get more CPU time?

Tags: scheduling, cpu

For simplicity ,let's suppose it's a single core CPU.

Will a  multi-threaded process hopefully get more CPU time?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, running a multi-threaded application on a single core will

- result in slight slowdown for CPU - bound applications because of the scheduling overhead and
- a possible speedup for (blocking) IO - bound applications, because the the IO can be done in parallel